# Subquery in MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, aggregation

I'm new in mongoDB and i want to get "COUNTS" from two related collection in createView.

```
userID     contestCount        namesCount
1          25                  5
2          5                   87
...
```

[My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHHtb.jpg)

Someone can help me.
Tnx

**Solved:**

Tnx 'Lohmar ASHAR'.

it was very helpfull, but if 'contests' item doesn't have 'names' child item, this query return wrong result. 
I changed query to this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
{ $lookup: { from: "contests", localField: "_id", foreignField: "createdBy", as: "cs"  }},  
{ $lookup: { from: "names", localField: "_id", foreignField: "createdBy", as: "ns"  }  }, 
{ $project: { "cs._id": 0, "ns._id": 0  }  }, 
{ $project: { contestsCount: {$size:  "$cs"}, namesCount: {$size: "$ns"}  }  }  ])
```

Comment: Show your MongoDB Collection and what you actually need to do. Asking for "please translate my code for me" is off-topic, nor is there any such thing as a direct translation. MongoDB is not an RDBMS. So if you just dumped your tables into collections and expect it all to work the same, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanx. It was corrected.

Comment: Rather than post screenshots you can get the JSON content of relevant documents and include it here. The data should be relevant for people to reproduce from and we cannot do that from pictures It also helps to show some attempt at writing the code yourself. People are happy to "help", but less happy if they think they are simply doing your job for free.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do a 2 step aggregation, in the first step accumulate names and contests into sets, and in the first get the length

```
db.names.aggregate(
{$group: {
    _id: "$createdBy"
    "c": {$addToSet: "$contestId"},
    "n": {$addToSet: "$_id"}
  }},
{$project: {
    _id: 1,
    c: {$size: "$c"},
    n: {$size: "$n"},
  }}
)
```

this assuming that name's creator and contest's creator can be/is one and the same, otherwise is not possible with the current design and you'll have to do 2 queries and join the data "by hand".